# Solarwinds API Poll Now

Tags: network-monitoring, solarwinds-orion

In the SolarWinds user interface, there is a button you can click within a switch or interface view to "Poll Now", instead of waiting for the regularly scheduled poll. I have been trying to figure out a way to recreate this functionality using the SolarWinds API. I've looked through [this](https://github.com/solarwinds/OrionSDK/wiki/REST) page, and it seems like I will need to use either the 'invoke' or 'update' operations, but there is almost no information on the actual usage. I have also tried examining the Javascript in the user interface, and can't make heads or tails of it.

I'm wondering if someone can point me towards some useful documentation as to what operations are actually available in the API (the 'invoke' operation requires you to give a 'verb' as an argument, but I can't find any kind of list or documentation as to what verbs are available). Does anyone know of any resources?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [Orion.Nodes SWIS Entity](http://solarwinds.github.io/OrionSDK/schema/Orion.Nodes.html) you can see in the bottom "PollNow" SWIS Verb. Unfortunatelly it is not so well documented what parameters it actually has (it can be seen in [SWQL Studio](https://chocolatey.org/packages/orionsdk) though). But you should be able to do it this way using Powershell:

```
$orionHost = "<hostname where orion is installed>" 
$orionUsername = "Admin" # fill login username to orion 
$orionPassword = "Pass" # fill login password to orion, this example counts that this is not empty string
$nodeIdToPoll = 1; # put id of the node

$Entity = "Orion.Nodes" 
$Verb = "PollNow" 
$Data = @($nodeIdToPoll)

[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true} 
$credentials = new-object PSCredential ($orionUsername , (ConvertTo-SecureString $orionPassword -AsPlainText -Force)) 
Invoke-RestMethod "https://$($orionHost):17778/SolarWinds/InformationService/v3/Json/Invoke/$Entity/$Verb" ` 
    -Method POST ` 
    -Body (ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $Data) ` 
    -Credential $credentials ` 
    -ContentType "application/json"
```